Initialize lua dissector ProtoField table inside protocol init function
I would like to initialize the fields protocol table inside the protocol init function, is it possible ?
I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to be working:
function my_protocol_addProtoFieds()
    local field_table = {}
    local attr_id = "test"
    local field_name = "proto." .. attr_id
    local field_abbr = attr_id
    local ltype = ftypes.BOOLEAN

    if ltype ~= nil then
        local field = ProtoField.new(field_name, field_abbr, ltype)
        table.insert(field_table, field)
    end
    my_protocol.fields = field_table
end

function my_protocol.init()
    -- read some initialization files
    my_protocol_addProtoFieds()
end


The solution is to extract configuration files dependant code out of the init function and to initialize the fields member as depicted in the question below.
How to add an array of fields as a ProtoField in Lua Dissector
